# Using jQuery to build HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is almost working but I am missing something.  I am building an html table and I have JQuery.  The idea is fairly simple.  I have a list of names which will populate the first column of the table body.  Next come two blank columns for some book keeping then a number of columns based on the number of days in the month of the date value passed into the function then a final bookkeeping column.

The general table structure is fine, the header and colgroups are fine. The thing that is biting me is the section of `<td></td>`'s in each body row that correspond the the days of the month.  They are not showing up in the resulting table.

There are two loops.  The first one builds the elements necessary to display the month day columns for the colgroup, header and body rows.  Again, the colgroup and header bits are working.  The `$trb` portion builds a single "row" of blank `td` elements that I hope to insert into each body row.  The problem is `$trb` is not being appended/inserted to the body rows.

I'm not seeing this, ideas?

```
$(function() {
    var list = ['11111 111', '2222 22222222', '3333333, 3333 3333333'];
    buildMonthTable(new Date(), list);

    function buildMonthTable(targetDate, list) {
        var myDate = new Date(targetDate.getTime());
        myDate.setDate(1);
        myDate.setHours(0);
        myDate.setMinutes(0);
        myDate.setSeconds(0);

        var lastDay = new Date(myDate.getTime());
        var dayNames = ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa']; 

        var $table = $('<table>');
        var $colGroup = $('<colgroup>');
        var $thead = $('<thead>');
        var $tbody = $('<tbody>');
        var $trh = $('<tr>');
        var $trb = $('<tr>');

        $trh.append('<th>Name</th>');
        $colGroup.append('<col class="colPlain colName"/>');
        $trh.append('<th>Last Date</th>');
        $colGroup.append('<col class="colPlain colRank"/>');
        $trh.append('<th>Month Total</th>');
        $colGroup.append('<col class="colPlain colTestDays"/>');

        for (lastDay = new Date(myDate.getTime()); 
            lastDay.getMonth() == myDate.getMonth();
            lastDay.setTime(lastDay.getTime() + 86400000)) {
            $trh.append('<th>' + lastDay.getDate() + '<br/>' 
                + dayNames[lastDay.getDay()] + '</th>');

            if (lastDay.getDay() % 2 == 0) {
                $colGroup.append('<col class="colPlain colDay"/>');
            } else {
                $colGroup.append('<col class="colShade colDay"/>');
            }

            $trb.append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');
        }

        $trh.append('<th>Practice Days This Month</th>');
        $colGroup.append('<col class="colPlain colTestDays"/>');
        $table.append($colGroup);

        $thead.append($trh);
        $table.append($thead);

        for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++) {
            var $bodyRow = $('<tr></tr>');
            $bodyRow.append('<td>' + list[i] 
                + '</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>');

        console.log($trb);
            $bodyRow.append($trb);   //  <=====  this is not appending
            $bodyRow.append('<td>&nbsp;</td>');

            $tbody.append($bodyRow);
        }
        $table.append($tbody);

        $("#content").append($table);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you update the title so it makes sense please

Comment: Why don't you use some templating? For example Moustache, Handlebars, or even KnockOut. They're quite easy to learn, and you can work nearly in HTML. You won't become crazy!! And, as Huangism says, please, give a correct title to your question

Comment: I would suggest creating a jsfiddle or the like with your setup. I have fixed your title so you might attract some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rafaelcastrocouto is correct, it is outputting... so I think you're problem is here:

```
var $bodyRow = $('<tr></tr>');
```

You want to have the tr tag at the top and close the tr at the bottom instead.

Also, I don't see your closing table tag either.

Answer (score 0):

The trb is appending as you can see [here](http://jsbin.com/doguru/1/edit)

```
$trb.append($('<p>x</p>')); // this will make you see lots of "x" in your table
$bodyRow.append($trb); //  <===== so this is appending
```

You should not append a tr(trb) inside another tr(bodyRow) the way you are doing and I guess you do not really want to do that rigth?!